# Conditional Styling in CSS

Tags: html, css, conditional-statements

For all I've read about it on the web, I've never got the hang of conditional CSS stylesheets.

I have a div #logo-container, which I get nice and central using some CSS3. For IE8 and below, I need to specify a position for it, as it's partially off-screen.

I have in my header:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<html class="ie8">
<![endif]-->

<!-- [if gt IE 8]>
<html>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

... and in my stylesheet, I have:

```
#logo-container{
...CSS3 styling...
}

.ie8 #logo-container{
...new styling...
}
```

But in IE Developer Tools, when I emulate IE8 the new styling doesn't take effect, although if I manually change it in the Styles panel it works.

What have I not understood? Thanks!

Comment: perhaps the emulation fails to trigger the condition? did you try manually adding the 'ie8' class to your html tag? doesn't this make it invalid for other browsers?

Comment: Your code looks right.

Comment: What are you using to position your logo?

Comment: Did you actually try to install IE8 and check it there? I know that emulation doesn't work all the time. For instance when you emulate safari, it will never do it right.

Comment: ABS - I'm using  {left: 50%, transform:translateX(-50%) ... and -webkit- etc} to center it within another div. So I'm just trying to do {left:0px} instead.   Plato - I did try to add "ie8" as a class in my html on that div, but it made no difference... I thought I didn't have to anyway?     Dingo - Hmm: I'll try installing IE8 tomorrow then, see if that makes a difference if I'm not doing anything obviously wrong. Thanks

Comment: BTW i think I have much more frequently seen a `ie-override-styles.css` that is only included within the IE comments

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks generally correct, but I'm not sure of the specificity of a an ID selector inside a class selector, so that could be an issue. Also there may be issues around keying off the `<html>` element.

Using ID selectors only on a conditional DIV works great however, here's the method I use:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><div id="ie8"><![endif]-->

        ... Your content ...

        <!--[if lte IE 8]></div><![endif]-->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#logo-container {
...CSS3 styling...
}

#ie8 #logo-container {
...new styling...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What have I not understood?

This right here:

> But in IE Developer Tools, when I emulate IE8 the new styling doesn't take effect, although if I manually change it in the Styles panel it works.

Testing old versions of IE is, sadly, not that convenient. You're not *actually* emulating an older version when you use the developer tools in IE, it's more of a poor attempt at faking it. Particularly if you're using IE10 or newer since they no longer support the conditional comments that you use.

The best approach is to run a virtual machine with a real installation of an older version of IE.

Microsoft themselves currently provide tools for this on [modern.ie](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms). It's as easy as selecting the version you want to test and download it for the virtual machine platform you want. At the time of writing they support HyperV, VirtualBox, VMware and VPC.

In short: your code is correct, it's your method of testing/emulating that's causing issues.